# For each unique entry, include all rows from another list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables as such:

**cars**: contains price of *some* parts for each car

```
| Car      | Parts          | Price  |
| -------- | -------------- | -------|
| A        | Windshield     | 100    |
| A        | Rims           | 50     |
| B        | Bumper         | 200    |
| B        | Rims           | 60     |
```

**parts**: contains all possible parts for a car

```
| Parts        |
|--------------|
| Windshield   |
| Rims         |
| Bumper       |
| Headlights   |
```

I want each car in **cars** to have every entry in **parts**. The end result should look like this:

```
| Car      | Parts          | Price  |
| -------- | -------------- | -------|
| A        | Windshield     | 100    |
| A        | Rims           | 50     |
| A        | Bumper         | 0      |
| A        | Headlights     | 0      |
| B        | Bumper         | 200    |
| B        | Rims           | 60     |
| B        | Windshield     | 0      |
| B        | Headlights     | 0      |
```

Any ideas on how I could do this?

PS: The order matters less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a calendar table approach:

```
SELECT c.Car, p.Parts, COALESCE(t.Price, 0) AS Price
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Car FROM cars) c
CROSS JOIN parts p
LEFT JOIN cars t
    ON t.Car = c.Car AND t.Parts = p.Parts
ORDER BY c.Car, p.Parts;
```

But as @Larnu has correctly pointed out in his comment, your schema should have a separate table containing all cars.  This would avoid the distinct select I have in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *insert* the additional rows into `cars`, then the code would look like:

```
insert into cars (car, parts, price)
    select c.car, p.part, 0
    from (select distinct car from cars) c cross join
         parts p
    where not exists (select 1
                      from cars c2
                      where c2.car = c.car and c2.part = c.part
                     );
```

This generates all combinations of cars and parts.  It then filters out the ones that don't already exist in `cars`.

Note that `left join` and `not exists` are pretty much the same in this context.  In an `insert` query, though, I usually use `not exists` because I think the intention is clearer.